# Weird discoloration in React Native when I only apply border radius to one side of a View

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, ios-simulator, iphone-se

I'm getting some weird discoloration when I only put a `borderRadius` of `10` on the left side of the red `View`.

[image]

When I have border radius on both sides, everything works okay:

[image]

And when I have no border radius on either side, it looks fine as well:

[image]

I'm viewing this on the iOS simulator for iPhone SE. Any help on why this is happening would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you share some code so that I can reproduce this exact behavior ?

Comment: Yeah, just a sec I'll try to make an example